# Adding two Columns values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to add ABSENCE and NORMAL column values and get the Reported column.
When I'm adding these 2 columns, I'm getting an empty cell.

I tried Below Queries

```
SELECT COMPANYID,EMPNO,
       sum( CASE  WHEN Attendence = 'Absence' THEN HOURS END ) ABSENCE,
       sum( CASE  WHEN Attendence = 'Normal' THEN HOURS END ) NORMAL,
       sum( CASE  WHEN Attendence = 'Overtime' THEN HOURS END ) OVERTIME,
       (Sum( CASE  WHEN Attendence = 'Absence' THEN HOURS END ) + sum( CASE  WHEN Attendence = 'Normal' THEN HOURS END )) Reported
FROM Time_Attendence
GROUP BY COMPANY_ID,EMP_NO

SELECT COMPANYID,EMPNO,ABSENCE,NORMAL,OVERTIME, (ABSENCE+NORMAL) AS Reported
FROm(
SELECT COMPANYID,EMPNO,
       sum( CASE  WHEN Attendence = 'Absence' THEN HOURS END ) ABSENCE,
       sum( CASE  WHEN Attendence = 'Normal' THEN HOURS END ) NORMAL,
       sum( CASE  WHEN Attendence = 'Overtime' THEN HOURS END ) OVERTIME,
FROM Time_Attendence
GROUP BY COMPANY_ID,EMP_NO)T
```

Both time I'm getting the same result.

[image]

Comment: just replace all occurences of `THEN HOURS END` with `THEN HOURS ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.